# What is difference between AV Foundation and VideoToolboox?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-toolbox

When to use AV Foundation and when to use Video ToolBox?
Can anyone please explain something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVFoundation is used for creating, editing and playing MPEG4 files and customize your app with powerful media functionalities.

While VideoToolbox uses the hardware's encoding and decoding capabilities

For further information please visit these websites,

For AVFoundation:- https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

For VideoToolbox :- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox

Comment: Does AVFoundation sit on top of VideoToolbox? I think this would help clarify the difference, as they are different abstraction levels